# Scroll bar that has a dynamic height

Tags: css, scrollbar, scrollbars

I created a page that has 2 pictures next to each other, each taking 50% width. the left is say 300x900, the right is 300x1800. I need to constrain the height to no more then 900 so i put a scroll on the taller pic (right side). both pics scale dynamically with the browser window, but the scroll height is staying at 900. I need it to shrink down in height dynamically like the pictures if the browser window is scaled down. I want the scrollbar to match scale in height to the pic on the left (the one with the max height of 900). Is this possible?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you show you code, how much you have done and what's the problem?

Comment: can you please make one fiddle for same ??

Comment: here is the page: bsmmediagroup.com/Testserver/Christine/test The CSS ID code for #Scroll is: {max-height: 900px; overflow-y: auto;} I am really new to this (and this is a wordpress site), so not sure what else you would need. Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help everyone!  Here is the answer i came up with and its working! (the 134.7% is the aspect ratio of the picture i need the "scrollbar" picture to link to.   `#Scroll {height: auto; max-height: 0px; padding-bottom: 134.7% ; overflow-y: auto}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

There are lots of solutions.
one way is to set the max-width of the div that has the taller pic inside.(You can set it in %)
Other way is to use media query
You can use javascript to change the css property of height etc etc.

For a specific answer you have to show some code.

this is the javascript code

```
windows.onresize=resizeImage;

function resizeImage{
    document.getElementById('Scroll').style.height=document.querySelector('.imageframe-1').offsetHeight+'px';
    }
```

this code gets the height of the span that contains image 1 and give it to the #Scroll div

Comment: here is the page: http://www.bsmmediagroup.com/Testserver/Christine/test/    The CSS ID code for #Scroll is: {max-height: 900px; overflow-y: auto;}           I am really new to this (and this is a wordpress site), so not sure what else you would need.  Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: I tried to add the code in several different places, but i must be doing something wrong since i cant get it to work... This is a wordpress site, where am i supposed to add the code you supplied? I am VERY new to this and am trying to learn. Thank you again for all the help!